# Can i convert this bash script to something works on windows?

Tags: bash, powershell, batch-file

We have a bash script that is used to enrich some data in one of the applications we have running on Linux Redhat, now we have moved the application to a windows server 2008, i need to have the script running, it's a simple script so if i can convert it to a windows batch file so that i can run it directly, else, is there a way to run t using windows powershell?

The script is as below:

```
#source OID.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.187.0.1
#source line /scripts/bgp/bgp.sh "$mga" "$text($2)" "$*"
nbr=$(echo $3 | cut -d . -f 12- | cut -d : -f 1)
if [ $2 = "idle" ]
then
/opt/OV/bin/nnmsnmpnotify.ovpl -v2c -a "$1" localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.11.666.1.1006 \
.1.3.6.1.4.1.11.666.2.1.0 OctetString "$2" \
.1.3.6.1.4.1.11.666.2.1.0 OctetString "$nbr"
else
/opt/OV/bin/nnmsnmpnotify.ovpl -v2c -a "$1" localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.11.666.1.1007 \
.1.3.6.1.4.1.11.666.2.1.0 OctetString "$2" \
.1.3.6.1.4.1.11.666.2.1.0 OctetString "$nbr"
Fi
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Kareem

Comment: what's wrong with [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com)?

Comment: PowerShell can do it, but it would help if you would tell the inputs and expected outputs for those of us aren't familiar with bash.

Comment: `is it possible to convert this bash script to something works on windows?` Yes. `Can i convert...` You tell me! Ok, my rudeness apart, As you can see there are 2 parts of this script - 1: string manipulation. 2: if/else statement. Both are possible with `cmd` also. So try to search how to do them in batch/powershell. & Unless you try & post your code here, It will be difficult to get help here. Good luck.

Comment: @jm666 Thanks, just downloaded it, can i use the commands from the windows command prompt? and if i attach the script to the application, do i have to tell the application to use cygwin? or it will run natively?

Comment: @anishsane Thanks for the feedback, may you please tell me the cmd command that is used to cut delimited text?

Comment: You can use for loop/command, with `delims=. tokens=11,*` for 1st cut & `delim=: tokens=1` options for 2nd cut. in cmd.exe, run `for /?` for exact syntax (it will also show syntax & examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

batch file approach: (literal translation of your code.)
The code snippet below is fairly easy to understand. Hence not providing any explanation. For more help run `for /?` & `if /?` in cmd.exe prompt for the syntax. If still any help is needed, please comment below the answer.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set inp=%3
for /f "delims=. tokens=11,*" %a in ("%inp%") do set cut1=%b
for /f "delims=: tokens=1" %a in ("!cut1!") do set nbr=%a

if "%2" == "idle" (
    C:\path\to\opt/OV/bin/nnmsnmpnotify.ovpl -v2c -a "%1" localhost 1.3.6.1.4.1.11.666.1.1006 .1.3.6.1.4.1.11.666.2.1.0 OctetString "%2"     .1.3.6.1.4.1.11.666.2.1.0 OctetString "!nbr!"
) else (
    C:\path\to\opt/OV/bin/nnmsnmpnotify.ovpl -v2c -a "%1" localhost 1.3.6.1.4.1.11.666.1.1007 .1.3.6.1.4.1.11.666.2.1.0 OctetString "%2"  .1.3.6.1.4.1.11.666.2.1.0 OctetString "!nbr!"
)
```

**NOTE:** Fill-in the paths for .ovpl etc properly. You would need to install parser for .ovpl files & may need to manually setup open-with option of .ovpl, or provide proper command as prefix to that ovpl file. e.g. instead of `./x.py` use `python ./x.py`.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, may you please guide me to a tutorial where i can learn how to do such script if i need them later.

Comment: General rule: 1. Divide your program into blocks. 2. Search for how to code these individual blocks. 3. google.